# Optimizing jQuery selector for checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have a selector that goes like this

```
$('.left_checkboxes:not(.Deleted,:hidden)').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
```

This is really painful for browser and it takes A LOT of time to check all of them (for example 3sec for around 20-25 checkboxes in list).

So I've tried optimizing it like so:

```
$(left_checkboxes + ':hidden').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
```

Where left_checkboxes = $('.left_checkboxes');

I also tried:

```
left_checkboxes.filter(':hidden').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
```

But no luck. These two of mine won't even work at all... Not sure why though. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Why do you try to use `.filter` when you seem to want `.not` ?

Comment: @dystroy Oh my god.... Thanks! i'm such an idiot :D

I just did :visible instead of hidden and it worked like a charm.... such a stupid miss...

Answer (score 0):

The important thing to not is the selector `$('.left_checkboxes')` should not execute in each iteration of the later code...

```
var left_checkboxes = $('.left_checkboxes');
```

then later

```
left_checkboxes.not('.Deleted,:hidden').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
```